# Click on login with Balosar project (wasm + openiddict), how to enable CORS?

Tags: blazor, openid, openiddict, blazor-hosted

I'm running [Balosar project](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples/Balosar) as follow:

I edit Balosar.Client Program.cs:

```cs
    options.ProviderOptions.Authority = "https://localhost:44360/";
```

I run server with

> dotnet run urls=https://localhost:44360

I run client with

> dotnet run

I connect a browser to https://localhost:44310, according to launchSetings.json of client project.

When I click on `Log In` in the browser I get the following in network console:
[image]

and the following message in the browser:

> There was an error trying to log you in: 'Network Error'

The server gets the `https://localhost:44360/.well-known/openid-configuration` request and sends the response (I can read it in the console), but the response never reaches the client.

I think I have to configure CORS, but I don't know where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Balosar project is set up with the Hosted template.

It ought to work when you just start the Server project (not the Client) and point a Browser at the Server URL. When the Client is served by the Server you don't need CORS.

When you want to launch the client form somwhere else you need to [add CORS settings in the Server project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-1).

Comment: restore projects +  run Server Project from visual studio (or dotnet run) all works fine. It goes wrong with `dotnet run -urls=urls=https://localhost:44360` but I assume it comes from line `options.ProviderOptions.Authority = "https://localhost:44310/"` of client `Program.cs` file.